# Nodejs :one time password generation with speakeasy package

Tags: node.js, express

I've a strange problem with speakeasy OTP verifcation and the OTP should be expired after 2 minutes.

**Generate token**

```
var secret = speakeasy.generateSecret({length: 20}).base32;

        var token = speakeasy.totp({
            secret: secret.base32,
            encoding: 'base32',
            time:120
        });
```

**Verify token**

```
 var verified = speakeasy.totp.verify({
            secret:req.params.secret,
            encoding: 'base32',
            token: req.params.token,
            time:120
        });
console.log(verified);
```

**case-1 fixed secret key**

when i change `secret` key to fixed key (ie `secret='676FGFG!@$#'`) OTP is never expired  console.log(verified); always returns `false`

**case-2 generate secret key with base32**

when i generate `secret` using  base32 (ie `secret = secret.base32`)OTP is not verified

console.log(verified); always returns `true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is that your secret is actually set to `undefined`:

```
var secret = speakeasy.generateSecret({length: 20}).base32;
                                                   ^^^^^^^ notice this

var token = speakeasy.totp({
              secret: secret.base32,
                            ^^^^^^^ and again here
```

The latter should be `secret : secret`, because the `secret` variable already contains the Base-32 string of the secret.

Secondly, `time` isn't used to set the expiry/period, that's what [`step`](https://github.com/speakeasyjs/speakeasy#verifying-a-token-and-calculating-a-delta) is for.

Since TOTP's are valid in a particular time *window*, you can't (AFAIK) set them to be valid until *"from now to 5 minutes in the future"*. What you can do is adjust the `window` value to allow for lenience during verification, where you can say that tokens that "belong" to timestamps between 5 minutes ago until 5 minutes in the future are also valid:

```
// creating the token
let token = speakeasy.totp({
  ...
  window : 10
});

// verifying the token:
let verified = speakeasy.verify({
  ...
  window : 10
});
```

The default `step` value is 30 seconds, which means that every 30 seconds a new token is generated. If you want that token to still verify as "valid" outside of that 30 second period, you can specify a window. A window of "10" means that all tokens between (10 * 30 seconds =) 5 minutes ago and 5 minutes into the future will be valid.

You can also set the step to 5 minutes, but if a user receives the token towards the end of the 5-minute validity period, they might only have 10 seconds left until the token is invalidated. That's why using a broader window instead of a larger step is better.

Make sure that any changes to `step` and/or `window` have to be made to both `speakeasy.totp()` and `speakeasy.verify()`.

Comment: from their doc   `Getting a time-based token for a custom time

var token = speakeasy.totp({
  secret: secret.base32,
  encoding: 'base32',
  time: 1453667708 // specified in seconds
});`

Comment: That's a custom time _stamp_, not a custom time _interval_. The value shown in the example (`1453667708`) represents "Sun Jan 24 21:35:08 CET 2016".

Comment: Can't see anything about setting `step` parameter documentation only conatins verifydoc

Comment: Here: https://github.com/speakeasyjs/speakeasy#verifying-a-token-and-calculating-a-delta And also here: https://github.com/speakeasyjs/speakeasy#specifying-a-window-for-verifying-hotp-and-totp

Comment: I've changed like this in OTP generation `{window:2,step:60}` and verifyDelta`{ step:120,
            window:2}`  verifyDelta returns this response `{
  "delta": 0
}`

Comment: I've messed up with all these things:(

Comment: Could you please give an answer how simply verify token with an expiration time of 5 min??

Comment: Thanks for your perfect explanation let me try it

Answer (score 2):

after wasting 4 hours, this works for me, please copy the entire code and try once. after tat you can modify it.

var secret = Speakeasy.generateSecret({ length: 6 });
                 res.send({ "secret": secret.base32 });

```
        async totpgenerate(request,response) { 
          response.send({
              "token": Speakeasy.time({
                  secret: request.body.secret,
                  encoding: "base32",
                  step:600,//10 mins
                  window:0
              })
          })
        }
        ,
        async totpvalidate(request,response) { 
          response.send({
              "valid": Speakeasy.time.verify({
                secret:request.body.secret,
                encoding: 'base32',
                token: request.body.token,
                step:600,//10 mins
                  window:0
              })
          })
        }
```

Comment: I hope you have learned something while wasting your 4 hours :)

Comment: Please add an explanation for what you have changed and why.

Comment: everywhere i found this combo: step = 'some value' and window =10 for +-5mins, but it wasn't working properly for me. i tried with window 0.finally it worked.whenever i changed window property it lasted for long,the token didnt expired. @Johannes